# How to assign disk unallocated space to ubuntu partition using terminal?

Tags: partitioning, virtualization, memory-usage, vmware-workstation, unallocated

I recently installed ubuntu-server on a VM and later on increased the virtual hard disk size from 10Gb to 70Gb.

Here is the result of `lsblk`.

```
user@ubuntuserver:/$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                         2:0    1    4K  0 disk 
loop0                       7:0    0 30.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9279
loop1                       7:1    0   55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop2                       7:2    0 70.6M  1 loop /snap/lxd/16922
loop3                       7:3    0 55.3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
loop4                       7:4    0 29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop5                       7:5    0 71.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/16099
sda                         8:0    0   70G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0    9G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0    9G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
sr1                        11:1    1 1024M  0 rom
```

As you can see 70Gb are available on `sda` but only 9Gb are assigned to `sda3` partition where the ubuntu-server resides. I am wondering how I can allocate the rest of the available space of `sda` to `sda3` through the terminal (as I have no access to the Esxi server that actually manages the VMs).

Note that ubuntu-server does not have a GUI, I can only connect to it through ssh to a root user, hence it has to be done using commands.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot manipulate a disk's partitions while any of its partitions is mounted.

That's why all partition changing advice begins with "boot from a live USB".

Comment: Apparently I can (and did) since it is an lvm: https://www.howtoforge.com/logical-volume-manager-how-can-i-extend-a-volume-group (check duplicate question i accidentally asked)